# Fluid Domain Box showing up during Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I am trying to render a simple water simulation, where 2 inflows run down ramps, and then collide and fall down. Everything is fine in the preview, but when I go to render, it works fine for a few frames, but then turns solid. I am trying to render in Cycles. Attached is the .blend file. Thank you for helping!

https://pasteall.org/blend/68301f4a1ce74b06bbd59be4abeaf343

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7a33.png ...works for me. Did you try to render on cpu?

Comment: I also tried rendering and got all 100 frames with no issues. The only time I saw the domain cube is if I moved the timeline outside the range of 0-100.

Comment: i am rendering on cpu

Comment: @M4RS From your description it sound to me as cache issue ... Increase +1 Domain Divisions and Bake fluid sim again.

Comment: I ended up making a new .blend file, and it works, thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future, select your domain object, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and subdivide it with <kbd>W</kbd> Then re-bake your fluid animation via *Physics > Settings > Liquid > Cache*. Select all under the type and bake. This allows the bake to have more vertices to determine the domain and flow.